# Store hexadecimal range in varbinary datatype

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I need to store a hexadecimal value in the table. But the problem is, when I insert the values manually, the error occurred.

The example for hexadecimal values that I need to store are:

```
10100000, 1010FFFF,
10120000, 1012FFFF
```

How can I insert the hexadecimal value with a `varbinary` data type.

[image: The error message]

How can I solve this issue?

UPDATE:

I've included the 0x prefix. But it still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the **0x** prefix.

So `1010FFFF` becomes `0x1010FFFF`

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-constants)

Comment: I've included the 0x prefix, but it still showing the same error.

Comment: @ASyK can you share the full SQL statement that you are trying to run? It'll make it easy to figure out the issue.

Comment: it's okay. the problem has been solved. Thank you so much for your help.